# Does SASS or LESS support variable mixin arguments?

Tags: sass, less

Something like (contrived LESS example):

```
.bg() {
    background: (@arguments);
}

#blah{
    .background(red, url('blah'))
    .background(blue)
}
```

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does work in LESSCSS, but you have 2 errors in your code. First, missing semicolons for statement terminators. Second, you defined a .bg() mixin but tried to reference it as .background(). Try this:

```
.bg() {
    background: (@arguments);
}

#blah{
    .bg(red, url('blah'));
    .bg(blue);
}
```

The output is exactly like you would expect:

```
#blah {
  background: red url('blah');
  background: blue;
}
```

You can run code samples to see if and how things like this compile in LESS CSS using [my LESS javascript-based converter](http://www.dopefly.com/LESS-Converter/less-converter.html) (files [on GitHub](https://github.com/NathanStrutz/LESS-Converter)), or just follow the [LESSCSS client-side usage](http://lesscss.org/#-client-side-usage) instructions to see it working on your own pages.

Comment: Your javascript-based converter does not accept the sample code, instead it states `No matching definition was found for .bg(#ff0000, url('blah'))`